# Create same coordinate system between two kinect (skd v2) sensors

Tags: c#, coordinates, kinect

Hi i would like to know if is any way to make the 2 sensors to understand the positions of each sensor to create a same coordinate system.The reason that i want this is because i take from both sensors human point cloud from depth map and i would to like to fusion of them.

```
// p.X p.Y p.Z from camera space points=> depth map => bodyIndex

if (!(Double.IsInfinity(p.X)) && !(Double.IsInfinity(p.Y)) && !(Double.IsInfinity(p.Z)))
{
   sb.Append(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1} {2}  \n", p.X, p.Y, p.Z));

   if (this.NewPointEvent != null)
   {
      this.NewPointEvent(this, new NewPointEventArgs(p.X, p.Y, p.Z));
      len++;
   }
}
```

Comment: The absolute location is the location of sensor(x,y,z) + new point.  So if each sensor location is determined and added to each point you will have same coordinate system.  To make it easy I would make one sensor location 0,0,0 and then measure distance between two sensors to get x,y,z of 2nd sensor.

Comment: Yes it can be done like that but i want accuracy to every measurement per  frame because i visualize the fusion point cloud.So if the distance(between the 2 sensors) isn't correct i would have problems.Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Go to Sears and buy a laser to measure distance between sensors.

Comment: So you're looking for transformation matrix (containing rotation and translation) between the two camera coordinate systems. That's basically a multi-camera calibration problem, ignoring camera intrinsics, only caring about the common extrinsic. You'll only need (at least) three different points, of which you know the coordinates in both cameras. Then you should be able to calculate/approximate the transformation matrix.